# Objective-C enum-map

Tags: objective-c, json

I am a Java programmer and learning objective C at the moment. For the purpose of creating JSON objects I want to translate the following Java-Pseudocode to objective C. However I got a *huge* amount of problems with that as it seems that everything I want is not available in objective C. My own variant takes up way more space and is way more complicated but as I am just a beginner I would like to know if there is a more simple and short way to achieve that.

## Java Code

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Parameters
{
    public enum Language {deDE};
    protected Language language = null;
    // ... other parameters ...
    protected static final Map<Language,String> languageToString = new HashMap<>();
    static {languageToString.put(Language.deDE,"de-DE");}

    Map<String,String> jsonProxy()
    {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        if(language!=null) {map.put("lang", languageToString.get(language));}
           return map;
    }
}
```

## My Objective-C try

```
@interface Parameters : NSObject

    enum Lang {deDE};

    extern NSMutableDictionary *langToString;

    - (id) proxyForJson;
extern int test;
@end

@implementation Parameters

enum Lang* lang = nil;
NSMutableDictionary *langToString;

-(CommunicationParameters*) init
{
self = [super init];
return self;
}  
+(void) initialize
{
langToString = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[langToString   setObject:@"de-DE"    forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:deDE]];
}

-(id) proxyForJson
{
NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
if(lang!=nil)
{
[dictionary setObject:[langToString objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:*lang]] forKey:@"lang"];
}
// does this work? is a mutable dictionary a subclass of dictionary?
return dictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks a bit like you've tried to translate the Java code line by line, which won't lead to anything but a headache. A number of things I'd like to point out:

1. Initialiser methods should always return type `id` (not a superclass).
2. Initialiser methods that do nothing but return `self` don't need to be implemented, this is because if no `init` method is provided for the class, it will go straight to invoking the superclass's `init` method.
3. The memory management for your `proxyForJson` method is wrong. You are returning an object that you own through a method whose name implies no ownership of the returned value. Instead, create the dictionary by using `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` as this result of this method has no owner.
4. Your class uses global variables that probably shouldn't be global. I'm not entirely sure, but I think it would be better to make `lang` an instance variable of your class that is set via an argument to an `init` method, e.g. `initWithLanguageID:`. Certainly this would be closer to your Java implementation.
5. Since enums are sequential and start from 0 (unless specifically written otherwise), you could probably avoid using a map entirely and use a simple static array of `NSString` objects, one for each entry of the `Lang` enumeration. Better yet, don't use an enum and allow the caller to specify the language as a string. From what I can see, the enumeration doesn't seem to have any other use but to map an integer to a string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments! I still have questions though:
1. Wouldn't this be very unsafe and generate a compiler warning because it needs an explicit cast? I mean how can the compiler differentiate then between:
a) NSString* x = [[NSString alloc] init];
b) NSSomethingTotallyDifferent y = [[NSString alloc] init];
3.) I use ARC which as I understand does all the memory management automatically. Do I still have to do this?
4.) Hm but isn't `lang` already global? I thought only `extern` declares global variables?
5.) My credo is to make invalid input as hard as possible so...

Comment: ... I don't like the user specifying a string because he could input gibberish then. But using an array is a great idea I've got to check that!

Comment: @kirdie: **1.** It's not unsafe, in fact, what you get back from `[[NSString alloc] init]` is likely not an `NSString` at all but a private subclass of `NSString` (because `NSString` is a [class cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html)). **3.** If ARC is enabled then there's no need to worry about it. **4.** The idea is to NOT have global variables. Basically, if you create 10 `Parameters` objects, they will all share the same `lang` but this is different to your Java implementation where each `Parameters` object...

Comment: ... has its own `lang` variable. **5.** You could create an `NSSet` of valid inputs, and on invalid input you could throw an exception (such as `NSInvalidArgumentException`). This way, you could separate data from your code (which is always a plus) by maintaining the list of valid languages in a plist file.